# Why does String.fromCharCode(0xd800) to String.fromCharCode(0xdfff) return the replacement character?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, character-encoding, codepoint

Why does this happen:

```js
> String.fromCharCode(0xd7FF)
'퟿'
> String.fromCharCode(0xd800)
'�'
> String.fromCharCode(0xdffe) // (and everything in between)
'�'
> String.fromCharCode(0xdfff)
'�'
> String.fromCharCode(0xe000)
''
```

DFFF₁₆ is 55296₁₀. I get the same results with `String.fromCodePoint()`.

Comment: Firefox console outputs `'\udffe'` for `String.fromCharCode(0xdffe)`? Chrome does show `"�"`

Comment: I found https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode that mentions these character codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code points U+D800 to U+DFFF are reserved for the UTF-16 encoding of [surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF). Effectively, these are characters which are *never* valid individually - they always come in *surrogate pairs* - a high surrogate followed by a low surrogate. (Confusingly, the "high surrogate" range is the range U+D800 to U+DBFF, and the "low surrogate" range is the range U+DC00 to U+DFFF.)

This pair of characters is combined in UTF-16 to represent a single character outside the Basic Multilingual Plane.

Outside this special meaning in UTF-16, these aren't valid characters. So it's reasonable for `String.fromCharCode` to basically say "you haven't provided valid string data" and use the Unicode replacement character instead.